# Finding totals in a Dataset

Tags: dataset

I have this `Dataset`:

```
data =
  {<|"Key" -> "h", "Values" -> {{10, 97}, {4, 59}, {2, 53}}|>,
   <|"Key" -> "c", "Values" -> {{1, 57}, {10, 34}, {2, 1}, {6, 74}, {9, 53}}|>,
   <|"Key" -> "e", "Values" -> {{6, 7}, {2, 61}, {1, 26}}|>,
   <|"Key" -> "g", "Values" -> {{2, 51}}|>,
   <|"Key" -> "b", "Values" -> {{1, 33}, {2, 13}, {2, 36}}|>,
   <|"Key" -> "d", "Values" -> {{2, 45}, {8, 85}, {4, 77}, {1, 88}}|>,
   <|"Key" -> "f", "Values" -> {{6, 55}}|>};

set = Dataset[data]
```

[image]

I want to find the row and column totals  and the grand total. This is easy when I convert `set` with `Normal`. For example:

Find total of first column

```
Normal @ set[All, "Values"] /. {a_, _} :> a // Flatten // Total
```

> 81

Find all row totals

```
Total /@ (Flatten /@ Normal @ set[All, "Values"])
```

> {225, 247, 103, 53, 87, 310, 61}

I would like to achieve results like the two examples above without going back to `Normal`. Executing

```
vals = set[All, "Values", Total]
```

I obtain the two row totals but loose the keys:

[image]

Executing

```
vals[All, Total]
```

[image]

I obtain  the row totals. (I don' t know a similar form to get the column totals)

Excluding `Normal` - which alternatives do I have to compute the totals of my `Dataset`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a clean way to achieve this:

```
set[All, {"Values" -> (Total[#, 2] &)}]
```

OR

```
set[All, {"Values" -> Total /* Total}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can also do:

```
set[All, {"Values" -> Apply[Total[{##}, 2] &]}]
```

OR

```
set[All, {"Values" -> Total@*Map[Total[#, 2] &]}]
```

For the other one:

```
set[All, 2, Total][Total, 1]
```

OR

```
set[All, "Values", Total][Total, 1]
```

> 81

Comment: Your ansatz is very interesting. With it I can even compute the "grand total": `set[All, "Values", Total][Total][Total]` (* 1086 *).

Comment: @eldo Yes indeed. Dataset is interesting, many approach to achieve same thing. I'm still learning.

Comment: @eldo Why not `set[Tr@*Flatten, "Values"]` or `set[Tr@*Flatten, 2]` for that, depending on your preference?

Answer (score 8):

First of all your second result can be had more directly with:

```
set[All, "Values", Total@*Flatten]
```

> ```
> {225, 247, 103, 53, 87, 310, 61}  (* as a Dataset *)
> ```

The other result can be had with:

```
set[Total@*Flatten, "Values", All, 1]
```

> ```
> 81
> ```

---

If you wish to preserve the first column of the `Dataset` then I would use:

```
set[All, Total@*Flatten ~MapAt~ "Values"]
```

[image]

---

I presumed from the use of `"Values"` in your own code that you wished to address items by key name, but if you prefer indexes as RunnyKine shows my methods work just as well:

```
set[All, 2, Tr@*Flatten]

set[Tr@*Flatten, 2, All, 1]

set[All, Tr@*Flatten ~MapAt~ 2]
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to keep the keys when doing the total by row you can also try

```
MyTotal[a_String] := a;
MyTotal[list_List] := Total[Flatten@list]

set[All, All, MyTotal]
```

[image]

Comment: @eldo Is this what you wanted?  I didn't realize you wished to preserve the left column.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My question is very general: "Which alternatives do I have..." So your answers are perfectly valid and I was just exploring them :)

Comment: @eldo Okay; in any case I added my method for this operation to my answer.  (mete, +1 from me, by the way.)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to your distinguished answers I can now do everything I wanted to do.

**Rows**

Row subtotals over a range

```
set[1 ;; 3, {"Values" -> Total}]
```

[image]

All row totals

```
totals =
 SortBy[set[All, {"Values" -> Total /* Total}], "Key"]
```

[image]

```
totals[BarChart[Reverse @ #,
   BarOrigin -> Left,
   ChartElementFunction -> "GradientScaleRectangle",
   ChartLabels -> ToString /@ Reverse @ Normal @ totals[Identity, "Key"],
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Thick],
   LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#, Right] &),
   Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
   ImageSize -> 500,
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
   ] &, "Values"]
```

[image]

**Columns**

Both Columns

```
set[All, "Values", Total][Total]
```

[image]

Second column total

```
set[All, "Values", Total][Total][[2]]
```

> 1005

Column total over a range

```
set[1 ;; 3, "Values", Total][Total][Total]
```

> 575

Grand total

```
set[Total @* Flatten, "Values"]
```

> 1086

I'm beginning to like `Dataset` ...

Comment: +1. I'm beginning to like `Dataset` myself, it's super convenient.